# scrape from web page into html

Tags: screen-scraping, html

I will ask you a rather simple question (probably).

I would like to scrape a web page, namely:
http://www.carmudi.com.bd/mitsubishi-lancer-ex-12877-43.html?s_category=29&s_q=se129ca11xgiintcarmx&s_dir=desc&s_no_result_page=1&disable_previous=true

i would like to extract the informations shown into the box on the right
(containing price, accident ... and all those subparamenters)
and push them into a simple Html template.

Into the html, I would like to show a table containing the image and then a bullet point with, for example,

- price
- condition

What is the easiest way to do that?

Thank you so much for the help.
cheers,

Vincenzo

Comment: Why would somebody help you with that here?

Comment: @abhitalks I think he is asking for a specific method to web scrape. Under SO rules, this seems apt

Answer (score 0):

You may implement this using two methods:

- Converting the required data to XML and then parse the data

Use Yahoo Query Language or YQL to parse the html to xml, ex:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com" and xpath='//div/h3/a'
```

The Xpath ***you*** need would be :

```
//*[@id="detail"]/div[1]/article/section[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody
```

- Use DOM structure to access each data via javscript

  var myDataTable = document.getElementById('detail').div[1].article.section[1].div[2].div[2].table;

  Later use **Element.innerHTML** property to access data.